# Decorating functions invoked in Vue messing with 'this' bindings?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, decorator

My Vue app is using a plain JS object to centralize database calls. I want to console log the calls. To that end I am decorating the object's methods, as illustrated below:

```
const Caller = {
    callingDB (arg1, arg2) { return ... } //Promise-wrapped db call here
}
const decorator = f => (...args) => {
    return f(...args).then(res => console.log(`Invoked method ${f.name} with ${args} for result: ${res}`))
}

Caller.callingDB = decorator(Caller.callingDB)
```

And in several Vue components I have component methods invoking the aforementioned plain object method as:
...

```
methods: {
 cMethod() { this.Caller.callingDB(arg1, arg2) }
}
```

There is a caveat, though: once decorated the Caller.callingDB method raises an error due to 'this' being undefined -- the dataflow in my app relies here and there on chained db calls via methods like the one illustrated above, all of which are invoked in similar fashion. Everything works fine without decoration.

I don't understand why these errors occur. Any hint as how I should rewrite my decorator to preserve all subsequent this-bounded invocations? Or did I miss the culprit behind these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const decorator = f => (...args) => {
    return f.apply(Caller, args).then(res => console.log(`Invoked method ${f.name} with ${args} for result: ${res}`))
}
```

Functions in js have the method `apply` which takes a `this` value as it's first argument and the arguments array as the second argument.

Here's a fiddle of the modified code in action https://jsfiddle.net/435h2gwp/

Comment: Thank you, applying against the 'this' value was definitely part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

to extend @chris.va.rao's answer:

without the need to hardcode the "`Caller`" object:

```
const Caller = {
        foo() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.counter = this.counter || 1;
          resolve(this.counter);
        }, 1000);
      });
    },
    callingDB(arg1, arg2) {
      return this.foo();
    } //Promise-wrapped db call here
}
function decorator (f) {

    return (...args) => f.apply(this,[...args])
    .then(res => console.log(`Invoked method ${f.name} with ${args} for result: ${res}`))
}


Caller.callingDB = decorator.bind(Caller)(Caller.callingDB);

Caller.callingDB(1, 2, 3);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwbhtmdf/)

Comment: Thank you very much, actually when I saw @chris.va.rao's answer I thought about abstracting over the particular this value he suggested to fit my example but replacing it with the more generic this variable, as you suggested. However this is going further than my question so fairness compels me to mark his answer -- which came first -- as the right one. Thank you very much nonetheless!

Comment: You are welcome it is just so ppl looking for this issue can get more insight ;)